# Run a script immediately after login before /etc/motd is read

Tags: debian, scripting, login

How can I run a script immediately after login before `/etc/motd` is read?

I' m not looking to run the script from within `/etc/profile.d` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

Comment: That should be possible via PAM.

Comment: @HaukeLaging coul you be more specific

Comment: No; if I was familiar enough with PAM then I would have written an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If login via ssh, check the `ForceCommand` option, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/33713680/1135424

Comment: How would the OP use ForceCommand to solve their problem? (Otherwise, this is a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer))